# Mac Mail "See More" messes up html formatting

Tags: email, html-email, apple-mail

I have an html email I send out.  It is formatted with tables because the original designer said, those were more reliable than divs for mail clients. All styles are inline:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px...">
```

When a single email is received, everything looks great.  But as soon as a thread is formed by mac mail, "See more" is inserted.

This messes up the formatting completely, moving cells out of alignment. The See More message appears to be inserted properly - within a single cell, kind of

```
   ...
   <td>
   My Text
   See More
   My Text
   </td>
```

But there are two of See More messages.  One toward the top, one toward the bottom.  Weird?  The first one doesn't actually hide any text - but repeats it!

```
Hi Kate
See More
Hi Kate
```

is what it looks like.  The second one does in fact hide text.  Has anyone had experience with this problem?  Are tables a mistake? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related, but in iOS on iPhone or iPad if someone chooses to use POP the full message will be truncated.

The work around is to have 1,019+ characters before your `</head>`.

See: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/ensure_that_your_entire_email_is_rendered_by_default_in_the_iphone_ipad